# "Справка > Ответить" исправить на что–нибудь получше

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

[Раздел справки, посвященный ответам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/answering), называется просто «Ответить». Это не очень красиво. Предлагаю выбрать для него новое название. Предложения — в ответах.

Какой смысл я хотел бы выразить новым названием раздела:

> **«Как производить/вырабатывать/разрабатывать решения задач и документировать их понятным и полным образом»**

К сожалению, не знаю, как выразить это не более чем в три слова.

Кстати, [аналогичный раздел про вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) называется «Как задавать вопросы».

Дополнительно: в списке категорий этот пункт сейчас идет последним. Предлагаю его перенести на второе место в списке, сразу после «Как задавать вопросы». 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Текущий вариант выглядит ужасно. Временно использовал "Как публиковать ответы". При необходимости, внесем изменения по результатам голосования.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: включил в вопрос предложение публиковать разные варианты.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: кстати, можно это ввести как нормальную практику. Сначала применять хоть какой-нибудь удовлетворительный вариант, а потом уже ждать, когда сообщество придумает и выберет лучший. А то сейчас выходит, что мы ждем лучшего по месяцу, а висит старый плохой вариант. Лучшее - враг хорошего. :)

Comment: Идея очень даже здравая за исключением двух но: 1) если есть хоть что-то вменяемое, тогда с большой вероятностью меньше людей примут участие в голосовании и выдвижению своих предложений, 2) есть вероятность, что голосование просто потеряется.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: они и так теряются )

Comment: Да, было бы интересным улучшением – «вопросы с нотификацией по истечению времени» :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: я давно подумываю о том, чтобы устроить небольшой скрам на Мете. Раз в пару недель публиковать список вопросов, по которым нужно принять решение или произвести работы. В конце применять переводы и закрывать другие задачи.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: В это хорошо впишется редактирование справки. Можно ставить задачи вроде "сделать описания N меток" или "локализовать интерфейс в документации". Что вы об этом думаете?

Answer (score 2):

Лаконичный вариант перевода

### Ответы

Вместе с этим меняем «Как задавать вопросы» на

### Вопросы

Эти варианты хорошо соотносятся с остальными заголовками, которые также выражены одним–двумя существительными.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант перевода

#### Как публиковать ответы

Comment: Здесь, как мне кажется, не охватывается весь круг действий с ответами. Публикация — это только как отформатировать и какие кнопки нажать. Хотелось бы акцент на «Как производить/вырабатывать/разрабатывать решения задач и документировать их понятным и полным образом». Но чтобы в три слова.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант перевода

#### Как отвечать на вопросы

Comment: хм, дубль получился ) удалю лишний

Comment: В этом случае получается, что сайт о вопроса: 1) "Как задавать вопросы", 2) "Как отвечать на вопросы". А где про ответы?)

Comment: про ответы в другом моем варианте: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1041/181472

Comment: а еще про ответы в слове «отвечать».